# How to enable SNI with Apache in Redhat 5.11

Tags: apache-2.2, redhat, sni

I am on redhat 5.11. I want to enable SNI with apache, but I only have Apache/2.2.3 + OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5. I am in a very similar situation like this https://access.redhat.com/discussions/1320983

Based on this, https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI, it seems I need to compile openssl and apache from source. Is it possible that I install the new openssl and apache from rpm packages, not compiling from source?

If I have to compile them from source, is it step-by-step guide? (I found a debian guide: https://www.howtoforge.com/enable-multiple-https-sites-on-one-ip-using-tls-extensions-on-debian-etch) and this: [Installing OpenSSL that supports SNI along with previous version of OpenSSL](https://serverfault.com/questions/599028/installing-openssl-that-supports-sni-along-with-previous-version-of-openssl)

Comment: Might be time to do an OS upgrade.

Comment: I never have experience on upgrading redhat 5 to 6. Will lots of things break?

Comment: RedHat provides a way to do an upgrade between majour releases, but they do not recommend using it.  https://access.redhat.com/solutions/21964  The best thing would be to just install a fresh system and copy the data over.

Comment: Nightmare for me....

Comment: RHEL 5 is in [Production 3 phase](https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/errata). You should not be deploying anything new on it, as it will go EOL soon. Migrate to a new RHEL 7 server with a current Apache and OpenSSL version.

Comment: @kenpeter, if you think that's a nightmare just keep in mind it's a bigger nightmare to troubleshoot an unsupported software configuration.  When things go wrong, and they will go wrong, you will have a hard time finding help for your shoe horned installation.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of people still running RHEL 5 / CentOS 5 for several reasons. Unfortunately RHEL 5 is out of support and additionally there was never a package with OpenSSL >= 1 for RHEL 5.

If you don't have any concerns about using a foreign repo then you can use "tuxad repo". It provides a different and more easy way **to update OpenSSL of RHEL 5 to the one of RHEL 6** (which is still supported):

1. Install tuxad repo for RHEL 5: rpm -i http://www.tuxad.de/repo/5/tuxad.rpm
2. Update packages: yum update

More details can be found here:

[www.tuxad.de/blog/archives/2014/11/19/openssl_updatesenhancements_for_rhel__centos_5](http://www.tuxad.de/blog/archives/2014/11/19/openssl_updatesenhancements_for_rhel__centos_5/index.html)
[www.tuxad.de/blog/archives/2018/07/21/tuxad_rh5_repo_now_with_phpopenssl1](http://www.tuxad.de/blog/archives/2018/07/21/tuxad_rh5_repo_now_with_phpopenssl1/index.html)

This repo contains several packages which are rebuild against OpenSSL 1:

- httpd (also include other enhancements like ECDH support)
- postfix
- dovecot
- curl
- lynx
- mutt
- vsftpd
- w3m
- wget
- php
- php from RHEL 6 backported (in separate repo "tuxad-php")

Comment: Dear God, WHY? Let it fade into the dustbin of history where it belongs.

Comment: :-) Well, sometimes there are requirements for this. Right now I was not able to install RHEL 7 on my router - or at least not able to install it RUNNABLE. And right now I still don't understand why an init system requires some bloat like a QR encoding library. ;-)